# Python Selenium Mac os.devnull - OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, selenium

**Edit**: Was able to solve the problem by uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling. Installed selenium via `conda install -c metaperl selenium`. Not sure exactly what that did to fix it, but wanted to post my solution just incase someone else happens upon this problem.

---

Trying to use a library that utilizes selenium pahantomjs webdriver. Any searching about turning off logging says to use `service_log_path=os.devnull` to be usable on any OS. Tried that setting `service_log_path='/dev/null'`, and using the default `None`, but to no avail. Any reason why I'm getting an error for `/dev/null/` not being a directory?

Here is my error:

```
/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sportsref-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/sportsref/utils.pyc in get_html(url)
     23     start = time.time()
     24     d = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=false']
---> 25                             ,service_log_path=r'/dev/null'
     26                             )
     27     d.set_window_size(10000, 10000)

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, executable_path, port, desired_capabilities, service_args, service_log_path)
     50             service_args=service_args,
     51             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 52         self.service.start()
     53 
     54         try:

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.pyc in start(self)
     72             self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     73                                             close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
---> 74                                             stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
     75         except TypeError:
     76             raise

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    709                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    710                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 711                                 errread, errwrite)
    712         except Exception:
    713             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1341                         raise
   1342                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1343                 raise child_exception
   1344 
   1345 

OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

Comment: so you tried setting it to os.devnull and it failed (not the /dev/null string)?

Comment: Correct, same error.